# how to execute step by step in C language?

Tags: c

I want to know how to execute step by step for my c program. I'm not getting answer as expected. So please tell me how to see step by step execution. I'm new to linux

Comment: You can use GDB. Google for how to use it.

Comment: As Yu Hao says, with GDB you can debug your program and execute it as you want

Comment: To execute any program step by step what you need is a debugger. For C and Linux most famous debugger is GDB as Yu Hao states.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many  debugging tools in Linux. I prefer gdb.

Usage:

while compiling use -g flag with. Ex:

```
gcc -g  *.c
```

to see step  by step execution use gdb tool:

```
ex:    gdb ./a.out
```

Then give `start` command to start main function.
Then press `s`  and continuosly press `enter` it will execute step by step.
Note: if it's a library function please press `n` instead of `s`.

to quit from execution press `q`.

Please refer `–-help` on debugging time to know more info. There are many instructions you have to know like run, break, next, info breakpoints..........

Comment: Start command is *"run"* or *"r"*. And btw you don't need the -g flag to debug, but -g includes more info for debugging.

Comment: `Then press “s” and continuosly press “enter” it will execute step by step.`  Hmm...

Answer (score 7):

Compile the program with '-g' option

example as

Compile the program

```
gcc test.c -g
```

which will generate a.out pass it with gdb

```
gdb a.out
```

then set breakpoint to  main

```
gdb) break main
```

Then run your program in gdb

```
gdb) run
```

then break point hits use 'n' or 'next' to step to different lines

```
gdb) n
```

Use 's' for stepping into function and 'p' printing var value

Example :

```
gdb) s <fun_name>
gdb) p x
```

Answer (score 1):

More convenient than gdb (especially for a beginer) may be some of IDEs. I'd suggest qtcreator.

At least a makefile (for ready project) will be required. You can also create a new project in qtcreator and import your files.